# IF/ELSE for header.tpl

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

I am working on a site that isn't SEO friendly.  Specifically, the header.tpl is inserted automatically into every page, with no option to change it based on the content of the page.  I.e., whether category = Bathroom or category = Kitchen, etc.

So I need an if/else command, but having trouble figuring it out in this instance, plus the change that goes along with it.

The code on the portfolio_category.php page is as follows, and what needs to change based on vf_category is parts/header.tpl (I can create Bathroomheader.tpl, Kitchensheader.tpl, etc so that relevant tpl has the relevant Title and Description tags for the page).

```
<?php
$vc_root_friendly = '.'; 
$vc_root_site = '.'; 
include_once("$vc_root_site/config.php");

include_once("$vc_includes_folder/IT.php");
$template_body = new HTML_Template_IT();
$template_body->loadTemplateFile("tpl_portfolio_category.html");

include_once("$vc_includes_folder/images.php");

if(!isset($_REQUEST['vf_category'])){
header("location:portfolio.php");
die();
}

//Show header
$template_header = new HTML_Template_IT();
$template_header->loadTemplateFile("parts/header.tpl",true,false);
$template_body->setVariable('header', $template_header->get());

//Show footer
$template_footer = new HTML_Template_IT();
$template_footer->loadTemplateFile("parts/footer.tpl",true,false);
$template_body->setVariable('footer', $template_footer->get());


$template_body->setVariable("image_category", $_REQUEST['vf_category']);

//Select photos for this category
etc.
```

Complicating things there is another page referenced in the code above:

```
tpl_portfolio_category.html
```

And this page too has its own header.tpl include:

```
<? include_once 'parts/header.tpl'; ?>
{header} 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr> 
<td  class="main"><h1><span class="firstLetter">{image_category}</span></h1>
  <p>
  </p>
  <table height="89" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- BEGIN block_thumb -->
    <tr> 
      <td width='180' height="120" background="./images/thumb-bg.gif"> <div             

align="center">{thumb1}</div></td>
      <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width='180' background="./images/thumb-bg.gif"> <div align="center">{thumb2}    

</div></td>
      <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width='180' background="./images/thumb-bg.gif"> <div align="center">{thumb3}

</div></td>
      <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>

    <td width='180' background="./images/thumb-bg.gif"> <div align="center">{thumb4}  
  </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="bottom"> 
      <td height="3"></td>
      <td height="3"></td>
      <td height="3"></td>
      <td height="3"></td>
      <td height="3"></td>
      <td height="3"></td>
      <td height="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- END block_thumb -->
  </table>
  <br> 
  <img src="images/spacer.gif"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  {footer}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!  I'm just trying to get parts/header.tpl to change to parts/Bathroomheader.tpl or parts/Kitchenheader.tpl based on the vf_category pulled from the database.  But it's driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance,
Gary

Comment: "if-statement" tag for a question about PHP and Smarty????  Q: What exactly *is* your question?  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways to do this, but in order to minimize the number of files you're changing, I suggest that you:
a) Pull the variable from the database and assign it to smarty, on your first php file, for both the header and body:

```
//Assuming you have retrieved $vf_category from your database;
$template_header->setVariable('vf_category', $vf_category);
$template_body->setVariable('vf_category', $vf_category);
```

b) Edit your file header.tpl and append the following code at the top:

```
{if 'vf_category' == 'some_value'}
    {include file="parts/Kitchenheader.tpl"};
{elseif 'vf_category' == 'other_value'}
    {include file="parts/Bathroomheader.tpl"};
{else}
    //the rest of the header.tpl code goes here
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will give this a try and report.